# prevent a number higher than the max be typed into a text box

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an input with type number. I have a min value of 0 and a max value produced by a variable (eg 5). Using the up/down arrow I can go between 0 and 5 only. how can I prevent anyone from typing in 6 or above?

I have set up as follows

```
<input type='number' id='quantity' name='quantity' min='0' max='$the_quantity_required'>
```

I have tried with readonly and disabled with the obvious result of preventing interaction with the text box. I don't know javascript but was wondering if there was anything in js that would do this?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It doesn't really matter what they type in, because when they come to submit the form it will trigger the validation - demo: https://jsfiddle.net/m3t7 ...type in "6" (or anything else outside the range you've specified) and press submit, and see what happens.

Comment: Even if you can submit a validated form with the number in range, it's still possible for someone to bypass your form and submit a number out of range. Whatever validation you do on the client you will need to do again on the server.

Comment: But yes you could handle the input or change event in JS and detect it that way, if you want to be really strict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        var el = document.querySelector('#quantity');
        el.addEventListener('input', function(){
            let val = this.value;
            let max = parseFloat(this.getAttribute('max'));
            val = parseFloat(val);
            if(isNaN(val)) this.value = '';
            if(val > max) this.value = max;
        });
    });
</script>
```